# Why Spring boot "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role" gets resolved with Eager fetch type?

Tags: java, spring

I'm writing a simple Spring boot application.

For the authentication part, I'm implementing a custom UserDetails. When I make a request to the login endpoint I get this exception:

`Authentication Failed: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.boot.cut_costs.config.security.CustomUserDetails.roles, could not initialize proxy - no Session`

`CustomUserDetails.java`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ACCOUNT_USER")
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "LOCKED")
    private boolean locked;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLE", 
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"), 
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID"))
    private Set<CustomRole> roles;

    public CustomUserDetails(String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked, Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities) { // jpa only
        this.setUsername(username);
        this.setPassword(password);
        this.roles = new HashSet<CustomRole>();
        for (GrantedAuthority authority: authorities) {
            roles.add(new CustomRole(authority.getAuthority()));
        }
    }

    public CustomUserDetails() { // jpa only
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public Set<CustomRole> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<CustomRole> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        ArrayList<String> authoritiesList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (CustomRole role: roles) {
            authoritiesList.add(role.getRole());
        }
        return AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(String.join(",", authoritiesList));
    }
    //Some more getters and setters ...

}
```

`CustomRole.java`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ACCOUNT_ROLE")
public class CustomRole {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ROLE_ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="ROLE")
    private String role;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    //delete if not necessary
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public CustomRole() {} //for jpa

    public CustomRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

When I make the fetch type `Eager` in `ManyToMany` annotation, it works.

I read in SO that this is not a good practice. First, I'd like to know why ? and second, I'd like to know what is the good practice ? Am I mixing Service layer and DAO here ?

Comment: I'm probably saying something wrong (and I expect to be corrected if that is the case) but I guess you end the transaction before trying to access to the lazy collection, thus without having loaded it. The eager mode obviously fixes that but i guess a more sensible way to do so would be to have a service method loading the collection in the same transaction to keep the entity with a lazy behaviour and still fetching the collection via the service when needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you use **Lazy** you load users without roles and roles will charge only when you use them

here you used **spring security** and you should put **Eager** to load all roles when you call CustomUserDetails,
it is not a good practice to use Eager in general cases because you load many details that you don't need them

Comment: Is there any better solution that using Eager fetch type ? e.g. by changing the design ?

Comment: you can use here Eager because you have not a big number of roles,so you can use Eager without problems , in my project i used EAGER like this `@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinTable(name="user_roles",
  joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
  inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 )
 private List<Role> roles;`